# Get Url on extension icon click and dispaly in popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am trying to fetch the current tab url in the popup display when an user clicks on the extension icon.

Till now I have tried `content-scripts` to set the inner html of a tag written in the popup.html. But it is giving me an inconsistent behaviour. Also I tried

> `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`

but it doesn't work when we are using popups.

**So what is best way to capture the url and display it in popup and get it work whenever the user clicks on the icon?**

Here is the manifest.json I am using:

```
{
  "name": "temp app",
  "description" : "temp app",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+F",
        "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+F"
      },
      "description": "Opens hello.html"
    }
  },
  "browser_action" : {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png",
    "default_title": "default app"
  },
  "permissions" : [
    "storage",
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"],
    "persistent" : false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I wrote the below code in popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js_src/script7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js_src/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span id="cu" class="cu">Default</span>
      <button id="cub" class="cub" >Get URL</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Source code of script7.js:

```
document.getElementById('cub').onclick = function() {
    // this method is not working while clicking the button
    alert('Method called');
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        $('#cu').html(tabs[0].url);
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    // window.onload giving problem when i clicking multiple time continuously on the icon
    // also I doubt this is the best way to implement it
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        $('#cu').html(tabs[0].url);
    });
}
```

Comment: There are many examples you can easily find e.g. [How can I get the URL of the current tab from a Google Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/14251218) No need for content scripts or onClicked.

Comment: Using chrome.tabs.query I am already fetching the url, but I am asking how can I invoke it and fetch automatically from popup.html on each time it gets clicked @wOxxOm

Comment: `how can I invoke it from popup.html` - the question is ambiguous and you didn't show your popup.html. It should have `<script src="popup.js"></script>` which loads popup.js where you can add event listeners and manipulate the DOM of the popup window.

Comment: ok I am going to attach the code and will also explain what is the problem with the script I have written

Comment: @wOxxOm, I have added the scripts, as you can see I am using the chrome.tabs.query to get the url but these are not working correctly all the time.

Comment: `onclick="get ` lacks a closing doublequote but the problem is that you shouldn't use inline code at all, see [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/a/25721457)

Comment: `these are not working correctly all the time` - this is vague, please add an example of incorrect behavior: what is the expected value/outcome, what is observed instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a code like this without JQuery, script7.js:

```
    //wait for the DOM to be Loaded
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        function getCurrUrl(){
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {
                //the active tab y the only one of the arrayOfTabs at index = 0
                var activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0];
                var activeTabUrl = activeTab.url; 
                document.getElementById("cu").innerHTML = activeTabUrl;
            })
        }
        document.getElementById("cub").addEventListener("click", getCurrUrl);
    });
```

This worked for me, i hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes, it is working. But is this the only way to get it done? I mean is it the most efficient way to achieve this, or we can do it by any other way like message passing or something else?